# How to show more rows in selectMultiple widget?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

How might one tell [the selectMultiple widget](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#SelectMultiple) to show more rows?

```
widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=GROUP_NAMES,
    description='Groups',
    disabled=False,
)
```

The html equivalent of adding [a size attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_size.asp) `size=10` to the select tag.

Not this but that...

[image: defaults to 3 rows]

[image: but we want lots of rows]

Comment: did you ever find out a solution?

Comment: @arctic-mood Not yet :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was resolved with ipywidgets version 7.0 back in mid-late 2017. You can now use

```
widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=GROUP_NAMES,
    description='Groups',
    rows=len(GROUP_NAMES)
    layout=Layout(width="100%")
```

And set both the width and the number of rows visible.

Comment: Thx.  [Found it](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/commit/2e77da43cae3dac9e39a76574e1a598f68d68208)

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure this is broken as the height and width parameters affect the surrounding `<div>` tags and not the the widget (see https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1133).

For now, if you want the box to resize to match the width and height of the containing items you can change the layout to `flex`.

```
widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=GROUP_NAMES,
    description='Groups',
    layout=Layout(display="flex", flex_flow='column')
)
```

The `height` argument appears to work if you do this, and the `width` works in your original example.